# Как при наведении курсора на текст сделать выпадающий список с номерами телефонов , заключенных в div?

Tags: html

Есть сайт, пытаюсь добавить такое вот всплывающее окно(см. ниже пример) по наведению курсора на определенный текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<p title="Этот текст будет показан при наведении">Просто текст</p>
```

текст показывает при наведении курсором, а как туда "засунуть" следующий `div`?

```
<div class="header-second__right flex">
                <div class="phone">
                                        <a href="tel:+79829349099" class="phone__number"><span>+7 (982)</span> 934-90-99</a>
                    <div class="phone__text">Работаем без выходных, с 8:00 до 21:00</div>
                </div>
```

просто в `title` никак не получается вписать этот участок кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы делаете эффект наведения мыши, то это делается не через параграфы и блоки, а через выпадающие списки. Вот пример такой реализации. Там несколько кривой HTML и CSS, за что я извиняюсь, так как я делал это только в начале изучения верстки, однако саму концепцию, я уверен, вы поймете:

```
<div id="content">
        <ul class="main">
            <li class="content"><u><a href="#">Просто текст</a></u></li>
            <li class="content"><u><a href="#">Просто текст</a></u></li>
            <li class="content"><u><a href="#">Просто текст</a></u>
                <ul id="shadow"><div class="mark">
                    <div class="pouring" id="first-div"><li><a href="#" class="pass">Просто текст</a></li></div>
                    <div class="pouring"><li><a href="#" class="pass">Просто текст</a></li></div>
                    <div class="pouring"><li><a href="#" class="pass">Просто текст</a></li></div>
                    <div class="pouring"><li><a href="#" class="pass">Просто текст</a></li></div>
                    <div class="pouring"><li><a href="#" class="pass">Просто текст</a></li></div>
                </div></ul></li>
            <li class="content"><u><a href="#">Просто текст</a></u></li>
            <li class="content"><u><a href="#">Просто текст</a></u></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```
.main {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}


.main > li {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}


.main > li:hover > ul {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out; 
}


.main > li > ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    opacity: 0.1;
    visibility: hidden;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
} 

li.content{
    margin-right: -13px;
}


li.content::after {
    content: " / ";
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 13px;
}


li.content:last-child::after{
    content: none;
}


div {
    background: #d6161d;
    height: 50px;
    color: white;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;
}

ul.main {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

div > ul > li {
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}


#shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #aeaeae;
    height: 184px;
}


li > ul > li {
    width: 250px;
    height: 30px;
    padding-top: 10px;
} 

div.pouring {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    width: 225px;
    height: 36px;
    color: #e5e5e5; 
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid #e5e5e5;
}

#first-div{
    height: 39px;
}

a.pass{
    color: #a7a7a7; 
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 7px;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 27px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

div#first-div a.pass {
    top: 11px;
}

a.pass:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.mark div a{
    margin-left: 15px;
}

.mark div:hover,
.mark div:hover a,
.mark a:hover {
    display: block;
    background-color: #e5e5e5;
    color: #d73135;
    align-items: center;
}

ul {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%
}
```

Если же вам надо не наведение мышью, а появление модалки при нажатии, то тут придется писать отдельную верстку и менять ее стили через обработчики на JS

Comment: P.S. выпадающий список на третьей вкладке моей менюшки.

Comment: P.S.S. верстка действительно очень кривая, но я надеюсь, что она все равно поможет вам понять концепцию